# Is it possible to install Microsoft SQL Server v.Next on Debian?

Tags: sql-server, linux, database, debian

Microsoft has released the relational DB engine part of the SQL Server for Linux, including Ubuntu 16.01.

Is it possible to use this to install it on Debian (Jessie, for example)? If so, What different requirements would I have to consider to get it working?

I know this is pretty new, but I'd appreciate any insight into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  You'll need to overcome a SSL dependency by using jessie-backports source.  I wasn't able to get the mssql-tools package to install however.  I also tested the latest version of Kubuntu.  SQL and mssql-tools installed without a hitch there.